# Javascript/Html: Load Html into FrameSet with onunload event

Tags: javascript, html, flash, wordpress, actionscript-2

Explanation of problem in full below, you could probably just skip to the code at the bottom if you want.

What happened is a impatient client wanted his swf banners converted to html5 without having to actually code them from scratch.  So i utilized Google's new tool, Swiffy.  I then tried to place this new generated html5 page in the header of the clients wordpress site.  I have gotten it to load as an iframe but the problem that I am encountering is when you click on a link on the loaded html5 page, it just loads the linked page in the iframe, not the parent page/window (which is to be expected).  I tried a bunch of other methods, and tried changing the AS2 links in the .fla as well but no luck.  I am guessing Swiffy can not read every AS2 code, and so it has been ignoring my "_blank", "_parent" when I use getURL.  Anyway, I have been trying to get it so when the iframe unloads to go to the linked page, it uses Java to just open the link on the parent page.  But iframes cant use the onunload event, but I am pretty sure framesets can.  So this is the code I was trying and it doesnt work.

```
<frameset rows="100%" onunload="window.open('http://www.goaefis.com/about-aefis/what-is-aefis/','_parent');">
<frame src="www.goaefis.com/banner_Test.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" /> 
</frameset>
```

Any help will be super appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean JavaScript, not "Java", in "it uses Java to just open the link on the parent page", right?

Answer (score 0):

try to use the "target" on your frames.

Here's a example:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html